# What does it mean if 'leap seconds are "smeared" so that no leap second table is needed'?

Tags: node.js, date, time, google-cloud-firestore

From the Google Cloud Firestore documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Timestamp#toDate

> ## Timestamp
>
> ### CLASS
>
> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of
>   any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of
>   seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time. It is encoded
>   using the Proleptic Gregorian Calendar which extends the Gregorian
>   calendar backwards to year one. **It is encoded assuming all minutes are
>   60 seconds long, i.e. leap seconds are "smeared" so that no leap
>   second table is needed for interpretation.** Range is from
>   0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z.

*Bold text is my emphasis*

What exactly does it mean by leap seconds are "smeared"?

In practice, day to day, let's say storing a `created` Timestamp in Firestore, and using it to order records whilst querying,

`let querySnap = await colRef.orderBy('created', 'asc').limit(10).get();`

do I need to consider it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Google's [documentation about time smearing](https://developers.google.com/time/smear):

> Since 2008, instead of applying leap seconds to our servers using
>   clock steps, we have "smeared" the extra second across the hours
>   before and after each leap. The leap smear applies to all Google
>   services, including all our APIs.

You and your users are highly unlikely to notice this effect, and it removes the need to write special code to handle sudden shifts in time that would normally be required to account for a leap second.